# kubernetes cluster initilization issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm` in `ubuntu 18.04`
by following [the link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu) but getting errors while using initializing the cluster as below:

`kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.x.x --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`

```
This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.`

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
`timed out waiting for the condition`

This error is likely caused by:
- The kubelet is not running
- The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error wi th the following commands:
- 'systemctl status kubelet'
- 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI , e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker :
- 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with :
- 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I looked the error, in google and got a link below https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83225

but this did not solve my problem either.

Please help with this.

Thank you in advance.

I have the images downloaded as below.

```
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                v1.20.2           43154ddb57a8   12 days ago     118MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.20.2           a27166429d98   12 days ago     116MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver            v1.20.2           a8c2fdb8bf76   12 days ago     122MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler            v1.20.2           ed2c44fbdd78   12 days ago     46.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                      3.4.13-0          0369cf4303ff   5 months ago    253MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                   1.7.0             bfe3a36ebd25   7 months ago    45.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                     3.2               80d28bedfe5d   11 months ago   683kB
```

Comment: Does the address assigned to `--apiserver-advertise-address` exist and is it accessible from all nodes in the cluster ?

Comment: --apiserver-advertise-address should never belong to pod network cidr. Actually it must belong to the master node.

Comment: @matt_j yes, that is the cluster host IP and is accessible from all host

Comment: It seems that your `--apiserver-advertise-address` address is within `pod-network-cidr` address range.
The `pods-network-cidr` should't overlap with the IP range of your VMs.
Please change `pods-network-cidr` or IP range of your VMs and let me know if it works.